# TableLayout within a ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, scrollview, tablelayout

I've built an app that has multiple edittext boxes within a tablelayout, this table layout is then within a ScrollView but for some reason the screen is not at all scrollable and the activty screen is not expandable when in XML design view in eclipse. I was wondering if someone could have a look at my code and find a fix for my problem.
thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >



        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip"
            >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_header_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:text="@string/str_ric"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:width="90dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_header_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/str_description"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:width="120dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_header_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/str_gps"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:width="90dp" />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:width="30dip" />

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="30dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="60dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            </TableRow>



            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>


                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""               
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""               
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""               
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""               
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_ric_8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_des_8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                >

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_gps_8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="50dip"
                android:layout_gravity=""               
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                </EditText>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="SaveSettings"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/str_Save" />

            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEW: I copied your xml and it seems to work fine in my 4.2 device. It is scrollable in my phone. As far as not expandable in xml design format, have you updated Eclipse? (Help > check for updates..) Some versions of eclipse with ADT is just not expanding the view when it's larger than the "working area".

OLD:You haven't closed your < /scrollview> , that should fix it

Comment: Ah, sorry something weird with my scrolling, editing my answer soon

Comment: ok no worries :) I just cant workout why it isn't working, i've had scrollviews like this working before, just not sure where ive gone wrong in this one

Comment: ok edited my answer, I would also try removing the margin on the scrollview, and put that on the tablelayout instead

Comment: hmm how strange, no updates available for my eclipse, changed it to use Android 4.2 but still no luck. i'm very confused

Comment: Are you inflating your view correctly, nothing weird in your class? Try to create a new project and paste the xml

Comment: aha, i've just found that if i tap and focus within one of the edittexts then the activity becomes scrollable but it will only do this if the keyboard is on screen.